# Facebook Graph API Explorer Read Page Messages

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to create an app that reads the messages sent to a page so I'm playing with Graph API Explorer to see what's possible.

I retrieved an access token with read_page_mailboxes and when I send a GET to /v2.5/my_page_name/conversations in explorer, I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#298) Requires extended permission: read_mailbox",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 298,
    "fbtrace_id": "GV+BcPhVkWw"
  }
}
```